kotest 5.8.1 eventually block failure
is there any difference between kotest’s 5.8.0 and 5.8.1  in terms of eventually block. I see that once I update to 5.8.1 eventually blocks are failing even after changing from io.kotest.assertions.timing to io.kotest.assertions.nondeterministic
I changed from
eventually(5000.milliseconds(), 300.milliseconds()) 
to
eventuallyConfig {
    duration = 5000.milliseconds()
    interval = 300.milliseconds()
}

o I need to add some other config as well?
Tried changing to
eventually {
   eventuallyConfig {
       duration = 5000.milliseconds()
       interval = 300.milliseconds()
   }
}


but the eventually block is failing

I did some work related to eventually, see https://github.com/kotest/kotest/pull/3864. Perhaps that affected you? Please raise an issue with more context and I'll have a look into it.

eventuallyConfig is a function that returns a config.
In your second example you are creating one, but not using it anywhere.
Try this:
val config = eventuallyConfig {
   duration = 5000.milliseconds()
   interval = 300.milliseconds()
}

eventually(config) {
   
}

